# Performance of Excel vs SQL table for Inserting and Searching Row

Tags: sql, excel

I want to input data in a table row-wise with every row ID increase in ascending order and later search for any row by ID. For this case, I'm acquainted that I can use Excel and later converting it to pandas DataFrame, I can search using the index operator, or else, I can use SQL DataBase and use WHERE clause to find a respective row. What is the time complexity of both cases? Is there any more efficient way I can opt?

Comment: honestly in my opinion there is no comparison. a database will always function better than a spreadsheet doing database function. don't go down the excel route if you ever need scalability, or multi user functionality.

Comment: Specifically for this case, do you know the advantage of the database over excel on the basis of time complexity?

Comment: db in 99% of cases is better.